# Pass argument or Ignore it if not passed BASH

Tags: bash, shell, conditional-statements, command-line-interface

Got an interesting scripting problem working with a Cli tool

`-a` means argument in this cli tool

In a Put or Post case, I must pass two arguments. So:

```
--verb "$1" \
    -a "$2" \
    -a "$3"
```

Passes in script

```
"put" "[\"name\"]" "testing this"
```

Works fine!

Then In a Get case, I must pass one argument. So:

```
--verb "$1" \
    -a "$2" \
    -a "$3"
```

Passes in script

```
"get" "[\"name\"]"
```

Of course this would fail because I MUST pass one argument but I did pass two, now that favors only the PUT operation, how do you think I handle this to make both PUT and GET work?

This is all in bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For more general-case handling (which will also work correctly with more than three arguments), construct an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in '') echo "ERROR: This must be run with bash, not sh" >&2; exit 1;; esac

# unconditionally, we always have a verb; assign to a variable then shift away
args=( --verb "$1" )   # this creates an array
shift                  # makes old $2 be $1, old $3 be $2, etc

# iterate over remaining arguments and add each preceded by '-a'
for arg in "$@"; do    # iterate over all args left after the shift
  args+=( -a "$arg" )  # for each, add '-a' then that arg to our array
done

# use the constructed array
runYourProgramWith "${args[@]}"
```

To *only* correctly handle `$3` being optional:

```
--verb "$1" \
    -a "$2" \
    ${3+ -a "$3" }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I think I'm a step closer
Using:
`--verb "$1" -a "$2" ${3+ -a "$3" }`

In a GET case it sets to 

`--verb "$1"  -a '[\"name\"]'  -a ''` which still doesn't work but I'm technically still passing two arguments even tho it's empty.
Possible `-a` isn't put in at all?

Comment: @badman, if you need to handle the _empty_ case and not just the _unset_ case, make it `${3:+ -a "$3" }` -- note the `:` before the `+`